# stopPropagation of a animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to stop a propagation of a animate function for one div, right now the opacity animation effects everything (html) and that is fine, but i want it to "skipp" one div. My code look like this!

jQuery:

```
var HTML = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];

$('.day-number').each(function() {
    this.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        $('html').animate({opacity:0.5}, function() {
            $(this).find('.input_info_cal').fadeIn(500);
        });
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});

$('.input_info_cal').each(function() {
    this.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});

HTML.addEventListener('click', function() {
    $('html').animate({opacity:1}, function() {
        $(this).find('.input_info_cal').fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

The div called ".input_info_cal" is the one that should not get opacity on it, but I just cant get it to work..

All help is thanked for!

Comment: Indeed, this has to do with changing your selector from `html` to `something that matches all containers except your specific <div>`. You might be interested in reading about the [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.

Comment: descendents of a tag can't have higher opacity than the outer tag. Simlarly can't display a descendant of a hidden tag...you'll need a new approach